# Display tabs conditionally in record page

Tags: lightning, app, conditional

In the custom record page for an object, can I show or hide tabs based on record type? For example, I want to show a tab "Incident Details" if record is an Incident and "Service Request Details" if record is a Service Request

Comment: You can create multiple lightning pages and bind them to the record types when they become activated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of combinations of tabs, for each combination:

1. Create a Formula Checkbox that is true only when you have this combination
2. On the Record Lightning Page, create a **Tabs** Component and include tabs appropiate for this combination.  Then add a Filter for this combination's **Tabs** under `Set Component Visability` using the Formula Checkbox from above.

I'm researching if there is a better way since my implementation has a large number of combinations: `9!`

Answer (score 1):

Please vote for this idea ([Lightning tabs - tab visibility filters](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003dfmQAA)) to add visibility filters for individual tabs in lightning tabs.

When I need to provide functionality for a specific subset of people it's not practical to provide a whole separate tab set for each possible combination of features. It'd be great to be able to toggle visibility of individual tabs.

Comment: This idea has been merged into this one: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H6VzyUAF/allow-conditional-tabs-for-lightning-app-builder-tab-component

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be if you add two set up tab components in record page and give them different visibility condition.